# Zeppelin is not allowing LDAP authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, openldap, apache-zeppelin, shiro

I am trying use Open LDAP to add user authentication in Zeppelin but even I created a user "test" and added it into the primary group "datalake_admin" and the secondary group "datalake_user", added a password and saved it, but each time I put it in zeppelin it says "The username and password that you entered don't match."

This is the shiro.ini configuration file for zeppelin

```
`
[main]
anyofrolesuser = org.apache.zeppelin.utils.AnyOfRolesUserAuthorizationFilter

# --------- working conf for datalake LDAP - simple
#ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapGroupRealm
# search base for ldap groups (only relevant for LdapGroupRealm):
#ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment[ldap.searchBase] = ou=group,dc=example,dc=com
#ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://localhost:389
#ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = cn={0},ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
#ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
# ----------

# --------- working conf for datalake LDAP - advanced
ldapRealm=org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm

ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism=simple
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url=ldap://localhost:389
ldapRealm.pagingSize = 200
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemUsername=cn=guest,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemPassword=#############
ldapRealm.authorizationEnabled=true
ldapRealm.searchBase=dc=example,dc=com


ldapRealm.userDnTemplate=cn={0},ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
# for zeppelin notebook permission filter when typing on search box
ldapRealm.userSearchAttributeName=uid

ldapRealm.memberAttribute=memberUid
ldapRealm.groupObjectClass=posixGroup
ldapRealm.memberAttributeValueTemplate=cn={0},ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

# enable support for nested groups using the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN operator
ldapRealm.groupSearchEnableMatchingRuleInChain = false
# optional mapping from physical groups to logical application roles
#ldapRealm.rolesByGroup = datalake_admin: datalake_admin, datalake_user: datalake_user
# optional list of roles that are allowed to authenticate. Incase not present all groups are allowed to authenticate (login).
# This changes nothing for url specific permissions that will continue to work as specified in [urls].
ldapRealm.allowedRolesForAuthentication = datalake_admin, datalake_user
#ldapRealm.permissionsByRole= user_role: "*", admin_role:"*"
# ----------


sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager

### If caching of user is required then uncomment below lines
#cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
#securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

### Enables 'HttpOnly' flag in Zeppelin cookies
cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
cookie.name = JSESSIONID
cookie.httpOnly = true
### Uncomment the below line only when Zeppelin is running over HTTPS
#cookie.secure = true
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie

securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
# 86,400,000 milliseconds = 24 hour
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 86400000
securityManager.realms = $ldapRealm
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
shiro.loginUrl = /api/login


[urls]
# This section is used for url-based security. For details see the shiro.ini documentation.
#
# You can secure interpreter, configuration and credential information by urls.
# Comment or uncomment the below urls that you want to hide:
# anon means the access is anonymous.
# authc means form based auth Security.
#
# IMPORTANT: Order matters: URL path expressions are evaluated against an incoming request
# in the order they are defined and the FIRST MATCH WINS.
#
# To allow anonymous access to all but the stated urls,
# uncomment the line second last line (/** = anon) and comment the last line (/** = authc)
#
/api/version = anon
/api/cluster/address = anon
# Allow all authenticated users to restart interpreters on a notebook page.
# Comment out the following line if you would like to authorize only admin users to restart interpreters.
/api/interpreter/setting/restart/** = authc
/api/interpreter/** = authc, anyofrolesuser[datalake_admin, datalake_user]
/api/notebook-repositories/** = authc, anyofrolesuser[datalake_admin, datalake_user]
/api/configurations/** = authc, anyofrolesuser[datalake_admin, datalake_user]
/api/credential/** = authc, anyofrolesuser[datalake_admin, datalake_user]
/api/admin/** = authc, anyofrolesuser[datalake_admin, datalake_user]
#/** = anon
/** = authc
`
```

I also checked the logs from Zeppelin and I see this each time I try to log in

```
`WARN [2024-03-12 18:50:13,118] ({qtp1047087935-16} AbstractAuthenticator.java[authenticate]:216) - Authentication failed for token submission [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - test, rememberMe=false].  Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException).
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal principal name: test
        at org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm.getUserDn(LdapRealm.java:928)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.getLdapPrincipal(DefaultLdapRealm.java:342)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.queryForAuthenticationInfo(DefaultLdapRealm.java:371)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm.queryForAuthenticationInfo(LdapRealm.java:263)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(DefaultLdapRealm.java:295)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(LdapRealm.java:210)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:571)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:273)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:275)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:260)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.rest.LoginRestApi.proceedToLogin(LoginRestApi.java:191)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.rest.LoginRestApi.postLogin(LoginRestApi.java:242)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1651)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:450)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1638)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1638)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1377)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:507)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1292)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jetty.TimedHandler.handle(TimedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
ERROR [2024-03-12 18:50:13,118] ({qtp1047087935-16} LoginRestApi.java[proceedToLogin]:213) - Exception in login: 
org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed for token submission [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - test, rememberMe=false].  Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException).
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:214)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:275)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:260)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.rest.LoginRestApi.proceedToLogin(LoginRestApi.java:191)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.rest.LoginRestApi.postLogin(LoginRestApi.java:242)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1651)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:450)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1638)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1638)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1377)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:507)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1292)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jetty.TimedHandler.handle(TimedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal principal name: test
        at org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm.getUserDn(LdapRealm.java:928)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.getLdapPrincipal(DefaultLdapRealm.java:342)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.queryForAuthenticationInfo(DefaultLdapRealm.java:371)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm.queryForAuthenticationInfo(LdapRealm.java:263)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(DefaultLdapRealm.java:295)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(LdapRealm.java:210)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:571)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:273)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
        ... 80 more
 INFO [2024-03-12 18:50:13,119] ({qtp1047087935-16} LoginRestApi.java[postLogin]:249) - {"status":"FORBIDDEN","message":""}`
```

The users and groups were created in LDAP Account Manager web interface